# How to add Microsoft Report Viewer in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, microsoft-reporting

I created one table and inside it there is field like `Company` (i.e., name of a company), `Question` and `Answer`. I also wrote a stored procedure for this, to retrieve `Question`, `Answer` and `Company` on the basis of the company name.

Now I want to add Microsoft Report Viewer, to display question and answer along with company name in the top.

The code of the stored procedure is:

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[sp_GenerateReport]
(
    @CompanyName varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
      Company,
      Question,
      avg(Answer)
FROM tbl_Answer 
where tbl_Answer.Company=@CompanyName
group by Question,Company

END
```

The column in the table:

```
Id            int               Unchecked
Company       varchar(50)       Checked
Dimension     int               Checked
Section       varchar(50)       Checked
Question      int               Checked
Answer        int               Checked
```

I want report in the format of a graph as seen in the example image below. In the top there should be the company name, and on the axes *Season* should be *Question* and *Points* should be *Answer*:

[image: Wanted graph]

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Walkthrough on how to Add Report Viewer Web Control on you web page

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252123.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251692.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251682.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use SSRS Sql server Reporting Service in order to make report but you have to get BI (Business Intelligence) it allow you to make report easily